# Bundler and Heroku: conditional gems / two different versions of a gem

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a gem that is not public and not on a publicly accessible repo (it is on the local filesystem) that I wish to use in a Heroku hosted app.

Bundler does not even allow this, for example:

```
group :production do
  gem 'mygem', :git => #giturl
end

group :development do
  gem "mygem", :require => "mygem", :path => "/gem_dev/mygem"
end

$ bundle install
...
You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources. You specified that mygem (>= 0) should come from source at vendor/cache and source at ...
```

I've used `bundle install --path vendor` and `bundle package` to try and get it to use the cache, but since the gem is a local path Bundler tells me (helpfully) that it won't cache it. To get around this I copied the .gem to vendor/cache and had the line in Gemfile:

```
gem 'mygem', :path => 'vendor/cache'
```

but I get this error from Bundler:

```
Could not find gem 'mygem (>= 0) ruby' in source at vendor/cache.
Source does not contain any versions of 'mygem (>= 0) ruby'
```

Heroku needs a valid path. Any ideas how I can get this to work for me?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with the current version (1.0.x). From http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html

> GIT AND PATH GEMS In Bundler 1.0, the bundle package command only
>   packages .gem files, not gems specified using the :git or :path
>   options. This will likely change in the future.

What follows is my opinion:

Why not? That surely wasn't a technical decision so I'm... aggrieved... Bundler is supposed to *solve* problems, and since it's written in Ruby by a couple of well known rubyists you'd expect (or I would) that they'd have taken the route that Ruby core has - we're adults, let us choose what we *really* want to do, regardless of whether the computer believes otherwise.

If I'm using Bundler and want to install a thousand different versions of a gem then that should be my business. A warning would've done. Let's hope the next version doesn't have this strange decision included in the code.